# Lens (K8s client) give error: exec: executable oci not found

Tags: kubernetes

I spent several hours looking at this [Lens](https://k8slens.dev/) error for K8s. I installed Python, OCI-CLI for Windows 10 (I downloaded oci-cli offline installation, and run python install.py) and configured cluster access. Using CMD works ok:

```
kubectl command works fine, even get pods command works
```

But using **Lens** it gives me the error when connecting

```
Error getting Credentials: exec: executable oci not found
```

[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution, it was to download kubectl.exe

https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/v1.21.0/bin/windows/amd64/kubectl.exe

I put it in a folder on the disk, example c:\kubenetes
add that folder to the **PATH** environment variable.

Restart the PC. Without reboot it didn't work.